# Controls with ContextMenuStrip

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, contextmenustrip

I am using VS2012, C#, Winforms.

My application generates about 100 label controls at runtime. I want the user to right-click on a label control, bring up a context menu strip. I have this part working. But I am having trouble determining which control is being clicked on when I try to respond to a the context menu item click event. How can I pass on the control to the menu item click event?

I am using this code to determine the source control but it always causes a null exception:

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
 {
     Control sourceControl = new Control();
     sourceControl = contextMenuStrip1.SourceControl;

     MessageBox.Show(sourceControl.Text);
 }
```

sourceControl always get a null from contextMenuStrip1.SourceControl;

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.sourcecontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `SourceControl` property can be null, as this property is best used during the opening event.  There are a couple of workarounds available.  Check these two out on StackOverflow:

[ContextMenuStrip.Owner Property null When Retrieving From Nested ToolStripMenuItem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12094528/590783)

[Get the SourceControl of my ContextMenuStrip when I use the shortcut key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5665042/590783)